# How to resize navbar and its content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a navbar in Bootstrap and I want to make it a little bit smaller.
I somehow did that, but my content of the navbar is bigger then it should be.
I don't know how to make it smaller to fit in the navbar or should it fit auto?

Code:

```
<nav class="navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:55px; height:45px;">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:23px;" id="fb"></i></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><input type="text" class="input-sm" id="usr" style="margin-top: 9px;" placeholder="Pronadjite prijatelje"></li>
            <li id="nameprofile"><a href="#profile" style="color:white" id="nameprofilea"><img src="fb%20profile%20image.jpg" width="25px" height="25px" style="margin-right: 9px;">Ime</a></li>
            <li><a href="#profile" style="color:white">Pocetna stranica<span class="badge">2</span></a></li>
            <li id="liprijatelji"><a href="#findfriends"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px; color:#1d2129;" id="findfriends"></i></a></li>
            <li id="liporuke"><a href="#poruke"><i class="fa fa-comments" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:20px; color:#1d2129;" id="poruke"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Text in code is not in English because I don't speak English.

Sorry if I made a mistake.

Comment: Have you added any extra css to this or is it just bootstrap? also what version of bootstrap - 3 or 4?

Comment: "Text in code is not english because i dont speak english." This is actually funny because you say in English that you don't speak English...

Comment: This is all what i have of CSS https://pastebin.com/QpY97sx1

@Badacadabra I write in English but i dont speak,its not the same

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guiding myself from the bootstrap tutorials, you would need to have `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">` instead of `<nav class="navbar-default">`. One of the reasons of the unexpected behaviour might be because you´re not adding this class.

Since you are using the .navbar class, then all you need to do is add the following css that overrides the default values of navbar.

```
.navbar{
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 50px; 
}
```

If you look at bootstrap defaul CSS the .navbar default values are:

```
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px; //This line is the one  that defines the min height, which we overrid in the code above
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

You might also need to add max-height to your css, since the container might grow if your content is bigger than your container.

[Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/fje6e4rm/)

Comment: Thank you!

But now i have problem.
http://i.imgur.com/sbP2LGY.jpg

As you can see,my hover exceeds(i dont know if this word is correct) over the navbar.

Comment: could you inspect your hovering item and tell me what class it has?

Comment: I checked the css code for bootstrap and none of the styles for hover seem to change the size of the elements, they just change the coloring. Try adding max-height to your nav style. You could also make your image smaller, to see if this fixes it. If changing the size of the image, fixes the problem, then you need to add a max height css rule to the image. Another thing you could try is to remove the padding and margin of the `<li id="nameprofile">` element. Since its probably outgrowing your navbar.

Comment: I inspect this element and i found a solution.
I dont know is this right way to do it.

I resized padding and margin with inspect element.

Image: http://i.imgur.com/bdjHvCm.jpg

Is this the right way to do it??

Comment: It seems that you indeed needed to resize, just remember to add this to the css. You could also try to remove the space on top (margin), altough this will create a new challeng of aligning your elements correctly

Comment: Not sure if it is the correct way, but I suppose it works well enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help!